# Android showing status bar click button

Tags: java, android, button, status

In my android app, i have 3 full screen ImageButtons ( horizontally inside LinearLayout) and i have hidden the status bar (full screen app)

The problem is that when i swipe down to show the status bar, the ImageButton on top, gets clicked, i tried detecting the clicks so i disable button's functionality if it is a swipe not a click like this

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    switch (event.getAction())
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
            y1 = event.getY();

            i=0;

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            y2 = event.getY();

            float deltaY = y2-y1; 
            if(deltaY < 10 && deltaY > -10)
            {
                flag=true;
            }
            else
            {
                flag=false;
            }
            break;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be very appreciated, Thank you in advance.

Edit 1 :

XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="3"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#567"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:onClick="speech"
        />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#456"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:onClick="pics"
        />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#345"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:id="@+id/vids"
        />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Java :

```
public class BirthdayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private float x1,x2;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_birthday);


    }

    public void speech(View v)
    {

        finish();
        Intent intent = new Intent(BirthdayActivity.this , SpeechActivity.class);
        BirthdayActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void pics(View v)
    {
        finish();
        Intent intent = new Intent(BirthdayActivity.this , PicsActivity.class);
        BirthdayActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
    }





    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        switch (event.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
                x1 = event.getY();

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                x2 = event.getY();

                float Delta = x2-x1;

                //if on actionUp, the distance is big == swipe 
                if(Delta < 5 && Delta(-5))
                {

                }
                else
                {

                }
                break;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The return of `onTouchEvent` is `true` if you consumed the action and `false` if you haven't.

So, you should to this -

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    switch (event.getAction())
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :{
            //something
            return true;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            //something else
            return true;
        }
    }
    //some other event, let system handle it
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

[docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent))

Comment: You didn't understand the question, the objective here is to remove this bug :

when swiping to show the status bar in full screen mode ( where status bar isn't visible ) ---> a button gets clicked .

Now how to prevent the click if there is a swipe, not a simple touch

Comment: That's precisely what I answered. You need to 'consume' the swipe.

Comment: Didn't work dude, i think the problem is that when the first click is in the very top edge of screen, and the status bar comes out is not detected by the onTouchEvent of the app, therefore the second click on the button, is detected as a first click ( according to the app )

Comment: Can you provide other code. (layout xml and relevant java part). I tried to do same, (three horizontal buttons in linear layout and full screen activity.) But couldn't reproduce your original problem. Also I didn't use `onTouchEvent` code.

Comment: The only thing in the code that bothers me is the methods `speech` not being static. Did you get any warnings about that. (But I don't think that may be cause of your problem)

Comment: nope, that method is only used in the button onClick.

Comment: Another workaround, is to declare the button, and findViewByID, then use the onClickListener, and put what's in that method in the listener.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did to (unsuccessfully) reproduce it.

Comment: Can you check it in other devices or maybe user espresso recorder to see what I'd being recorded when you swipe. Mine is API 23 with no problem.

Comment: same, i have Android 6.0.1, when i try to get the status bar down, and stop my swipe in the first button, it takes it as a click

Comment: Can you check with espresso exactly what is being recorded? You should find a button 'record espresso tests' in some menu in android studio.

Comment: when i swipe to get the status bar down i get : 

Tap AppCompatImageView with ID speech

Comment: Then I don't if there is any workaround for this. You should update the question with this info.